# What am I? Series 1.2

Tags: riddle, word

"The difficulty is not guessing the riddle. It is to **explain** the riddle" anyways, let's start.

> Really, you square me and cut corners of the square just to explain.. that food is equals to 4?! Disgusting false misleading proof.
>
> Well, yeah, I am commonly known to be related to that food.
>
> So kids sometimes draw me, but most of them made me ugly or became another form that looks similar to me but stretched.
>
> I know some people say that I can't be inside that 3 dimensional blocky game or it breaks the game! Look how powerful I am!
>
> Let me just be honest with you. You suck at counting how many sides I have. By the way, "infinite" is not a number, nor an answer. (Maybe no need to explain this, because I believe this is depends on your belief.)
>
> Even in the kids drawing, I was commonly quarterly drawn with lines flying out of me.
>
> A multiple of me would be helpful in showing how primary and secondary colours relate.
>
> Also, people "draw" me to shut another people out in heretic and rebellance. But with the power of love,  one can win by "drawing" a bigger me!

So, what am I?

Comment: that food is wirdplay?

Comment: @Jasen Is "pun" considered a word play?

Comment: I think so. I don't know all the rule here.

Answer (score 5):

> A circle!

because

> Really, you square me and cut corners of the square just to explain..

refers to

> squaring the cricle

and

> that food is equals to 4?! Disgusting false misleading proof.
>      Well, yeah, I am commonly known to be related to that food.

is talking about

> the value of pi

whereas

> So kids sometimes draw me, but most of them made me ugly or became 
>   another form that looks similar to me but stretched.

is just literal

> I know some people say that I can't be inside that 3 dimensional 
>   blocky game or it breaks the game! Look how powerful I am!

could be

> Minecraft - even the watermelons are box shaped.

> Let me just be honest with you. You suck at counting how many sides I have. By the way, "infinite" is not a number, nor an answer. (Maybe no need to explain this, because I believe this is depends on your belief.)
>
> Even in the kids drawing, I was commonly quarterly drawn with lines flying out of me.

kids drawing

> the sun.

and

> A multiple of me would be helpful in showing how primary and secondary colours relate.

would be

> a Venn diagram showing colout mixing

and

> Also, people "draw" me to shut another people out in heretic and rebellance.

is

> a magic circle

but

> But with the power of love, one can win by "drawing" a bigger me!

i'm not sure,

> circle of friends perhaps.

Comment: You are correct! But the explanation need to be correct before I give u the tick. A very good attempt. "Really, you square... Disgusting false misleading proof" is refering to a thing. But the "Well, yeah, I am commonly known to be related to that food" is kind of correct. The "Also, people "draw" me to shut... a bigger me!" is refering to a thing. Not separated. But your answer "circle of friends" is very related to that paragraph!

Comment: The disgusting false misleading proof is the one where you start with a unit circle and a circumscribed square, and then gradually "flip" corners of the square in to the circle making shapes with more and more sides, all of them axis-parallel, getting closer and closer to the circle -- but always with perimeter 8. Then you say "so in the limit we see that the circle's perimeter is 8, so pi=4", which of course is entirely wrong.

Comment: really, such a thing exists?  $A=\pi r^2$ is a simple disproof.

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4).an exercise that can mislead someone to believe that pi=4.

Answer (score 3):

First response on this forum. I'll give it a shot... I'm sure I'm off a bit.

Really, you square me and cut corners of the square just to explain.. that food is equals to 4?! Disgusting false misleading proof.

> "Square me" is possibly related to the Pythagorean theorem? "Food equals 4" is a pyramid with 4 sides not counting the base.

Well, yeah, I am commonly known to be related to that food.

> The food pyramid.

So kids sometimes draw me, but most of them made me ugly or became another form that looks similar to me but stretched.

> There are multiple types of triangles and are based on side length.

I know some people say that I can't be inside that 3 dimensional blocky game or it breaks the game! Look how powerful I am!

> You got me! :)

Let me just be honest with you. You suck at counting how many sides I have. By the way, "infinite" is not a number, nor an answer. (Maybe no need to explain this, because I believe this is depends on your belief.)

> You could mathematically split a triangle into an infinite number of other triangles.

Even in the kids drawing, I was commonly quarterly drawn with lines flying out of me.

> 4 triangles = a kite with a string.

A multiple of me would be helpful in showing how primary and secondary colours relate.

> 3 sides on a triangle; 3 primary colors.

Also, people "draw" me to shut another people out in heretic and rebellance. But with the power of love, one can win by "drawing" a bigger me!

> I have to think about this one as well! :)

That's my take at least. Was fun :)

Comment: Very good try, at least you get the right topic (not right answer).